# MySQL - Counting a count?

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to aggregate some data I've pulled from my MySQL db.

Query I'm using is:

```
SELECT `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED`,
COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=1,NAME,NULL)) as Ext, 
COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=0,NAME,NULL)) as NoExt,
COUNT(distinct NAME) as `All`
FROM sourcelist, main_small 
WHERE sourcelist.SourcePUID = 'My_Variable' AND main_small.NAME = sourcelist.SourceFileName 
GROUP BY `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED` ORDER BY `DROID_V` ASC, `SIG_V` ASC, `SPEED`
```

And I wondered if there was a way of counting this result, so I can make a new table that would show me something like:

Every distinct PUID, (count of distinct DROID_V), (count of distinct Sig_V), (SUM of total hits for NAME)  WHERE sourcelist.SourcePUID = 'My_Variable' AND main_small.NAME = sourcelist.SourceFileName

As you can see, I'm really not very good at SQL!

Source table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
 `DROID_V` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Sig_V` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SPEED` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ID` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PARENT_ID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `URI` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FILE_PATH` varchar(68) DEFAULT NULL,
 `NAME` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
 `METHOD` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `STATUS` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SIZE` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `TYPE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `EXT` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `LAST_MODIFIED` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `EXTENSION_MISMATCH` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `MD5_HASH` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FORMAT_COUNT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PUID` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `MIME_TYPE` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FORMAT_NAME` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FORMAT_VERSION` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `INDEX` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`INDEX`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=960831 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

example records:

```
5;"v37";"slow";"10266";;"file:";"V1-FL425817.tif";"V1-FL425817.tif";"BINARY_SIG";"MultipleIdenti";"20603284";"FILE";"tif";"2008-11-03";;;;"fmt/7";"image/tiff";"Tagged Ima";"3";"191977"
5;"v37";"slow";"10268";;"file:";"V1-FL425817.tif";"V1-FL425817.tif";"BINARY_SIG";"MultipleIdenti";"20603284";"FILE";"tif";"2008-11-03";;;;"fmt/8";"image/tiff";"Tagged Ima";"4";"191978"
5;"v37";"slow";"10269";;"file:";"V1-FL425817.tif";"V1-FL425817.tif";"BINARY_SIG";"MultipleIdenti";"20603284";"FILE";"tif";"2008-11-03";;;;"fmt/9";"image/tiff";"Tagged Ima";"5";"191979"
5;"v37";"slow";"10270";;"file:";"V1-FL425817.tif";"V1-FL425817.tif";"BINARY_SIG";"MultipleIdenti";"20603284";"FILE";"tif";"2008-11-03";;;;"fmt/10";"image/tiff";"Tagged Ima";"6";"191980"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure just do something like

```
Select Count(*) From (Select * From SomeTable) adummynamesoSqlParserDoesntgetupset
```

so put your query in parentheses after `FROM` give it a unique name, and you can treat it like a table or a view.

Comment: Oh! cool! Thats really useful, thank you! I'll have an explore.